# MySQL ranking feature

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to create a ranking system using the data in my table. It has 2 columns, name and score. One user can have multiple scores. This is what I have so far:

```
("SELECT name, score, FIND_IN_SET( score, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT ( score ORDER BY score DESC ) FROM data )) AS rank FROM scores");
```

But this command lists all the user's previous scores when I only need the highest score.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: what are the other fields of `data` table? does it have `name` or `id` of a `user`?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: share your table data with create query

Comment: @RavinderReddy yes it has an id for each row which is auto increment and a userid which is unique to each user generated by the application

Comment: You mentioned about one user multiple score. So whats the business  logic for the ranking? I might be help you with query if have this information clear.

Comment: @RameshDahiya its like a competition where the user can get a score multiple times (so the scores are always changing) and use the best score to compete with other users and see who is better.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT name, sum(score) from scores group by name order by sum(score) desc limit 1
```

And if you don't want to sum then use

```
SELECT name, max(score) from scores
```

Comment: select name, max(score) from scores is the right answer to the question. perhaps a "group by name" could be added. Whoever downvoted this, instead of just trolling people, leave a comment about why you did downvote.

Answer (score 0):

The below query will pop the list of name in the order of highest score respectively.

```
select name, max(score) as score from scores  group by name order by score desc
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use SELECT DISTINCT name, score ... 
and Select TOP 1 and ORDER BY